# how to create desktop sharing web conference through web application?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible to share desktop screen on web site through .net c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042573/is-it-possible-to-share-desktop-screen-on-web-site-through-net-c)

I want to create a desktop sharing web conference like application where one user will demonstrate anything on its desktop and others will view what he is doing.
Is any one having detailed steps about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you question is to vague is it a project you still need to work on? if so heres what you could do:

1 - make the app initialize a connection with another computer (both running the same app)
2 - make the app assign different roles to both clients running (handler and the viewer)

3 - make the app render bitmaps of you current screen to a server directory (you want to use around 15 fps)
4 - create a method wich checks if those bitmaps are being rendered by the viewer role

5 - If rendered succesfully delete saved bitmaps.

This is a CPU and Bandwidth heavy solution you might want to add some filter to the bitmaps to prevent huge files.